# Fail to send data to server using device

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm new to Android and after a long time I finally manage to create a database using PHP scripts and MySQL.

While I'm using the Android Studio emulator I do succeed sending data to the database but when I run the application on my device I failed to do so.
I don't get any error and the app keeps running (not crushing) but the database doesn't get the data.

This is the doInbackground method in my BackgroundTask class:

```
@Override
// send info to MySQL DB
// it gets 4 parameters - the first if the opertaion should be "register" and the others are
// user info (name,pass,gender)
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // the ip is default for localhost
    String reg_url = "http://**MyIP**/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://**MyIP**/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if (Objects.equals(method, "register")){
        String userName = params[1];
        String userPass = params[2];
        String gender = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            // run the register php script.
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            // applied the "userName,"userPass" and "gender" that I define in the POST (at the register.php)
            // the info the user typed.
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("userName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("userPass", "UTF-8") + "=" +URLEncoder.encode(userPass,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("gender", "UTF-8") + "=" +URLEncoder.encode(gender,"UTF-8");
            // write the data to server
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Registration Successs";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `**MyIP**` is accessible from the device?

Comment: also `e.printStackTrace();` should print exception stacktrace to the log. Do you get anything in the log?

Comment: `I will post it ASAP` 5 minutes does not look like ASAP.

Comment: MyIP is the IP of my computer - how do I know if the IP is accessible from my device? and I dont get anything in the log.

Comment: `IP of my computer` - which one? real internet IP, or inner network IP, or maybe 127.0.0.1? `how do I know if the IP is accessible from my device` - that's what you have to figure out on your own. Open your IP in the web browser of the device?

Comment: if your device is marshmallow or above then you will need runtime permissions, also please post your stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do setting of the wampp server in your pc. i will give a URL for doing your work. please any query ask for it.

http://androidcss.com/android/test-android-app-php-localhost-wamp/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Connect your PC and android device to same wifi network.

If your running on windows enter `ipconfig` on `cmd` and if it is ubuntu run `ifconfig` on `terminal` to get ip address

it'll be like `192.168.0.*`. If `**MyIP**` and `IP Address` which you've got are same then ignore it.

Be Sure that you've given permissions to access internet in manifest file.